# Error in SSH connection to instance, While performing Burn CPU of Chaos Monkey tool using Simian Army tool

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, netflix

I am using Netflix/Simian army tool. I am not able to perform burn CPU strategy of chaos Monkey as I am getting error in SSH connection to instance. The error mentioned below.

I am running Chaos monkey in local system(windows 7). I am using ubuntu instance(Amazon EC2) on which performing burn CPU. My instance is running in Tokyo(ap-northeast-1) region. But I am getting an `Unauthorized for eu-central-1` error

```
    2015-04-01 10:52:48.147 - INFO  BasicChaosInstanceSelector - [BasicChaosInstanceSelector.java:83] Group monkey [type ASG] has disabled probability: 0.0
    2015-04-01 10:52:48.154 - INFO  BasicChaosInstanceSelector - [BasicChaosInstanceSelector.java:65] Randomly selecting 1 from 1 instances, excluding null
    2015-04-01 10:52:54.302 - WARN  ChaosInstance - [ChaosInstance.java:105] Error making SSH connection to instance 
    at org.jclouds.rest.AuthorizationException: POST https://ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ HTTP/1.1 -> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
    at org.jclouds.aws.handlers.ParseAWSErrorFromXmlContent.refineException(ParseAWSErrorFromXmlContent.java:123)
    at org.jclouds.aws.handlers.ParseAWSErrorFromXmlContent.handleError(ParseAWSErrorFromXmlContent.java:92)
    at org.jclouds.http.handlers.DelegatingErrorHandler.handleError(DelegatingErrorHandler.java:69)
    at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.shouldContinue(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:182)
    at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.invoke(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:152)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeSyncToAsyncHttpMethod.invoke(InvokeSyncToAsyncHttpMethod.java:133)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeSyncToAsyncHttpMethod.apply(InvokeSyncToAsyncHttpMethod.java:99)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeSyncToAsyncHttpMethod.apply(InvokeSyncToAsyncHttpMethod.java:60)
    at org.jclouds.reflect.FunctionalReflection$FunctionalInvocationHandler.handleInvocation(FunctionalReflection.java:119)
    at com.google.common.reflect.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:70)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.describeInstancesInRegion(Unknown Source)
    at org.jclouds.ec2.compute.strategy.EC2ListNodesStrategy$2.apply(EC2ListNodesStrategy.java:151)
    at org.jclouds.ec2.compute.strategy.EC2ListNodesStrategy$2.apply(EC2ListNodesStrategy.java:147)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:860)
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterables$3.next(Iterables.java:512)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterables$3.next(Iterables.java:505)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.hasNext(Iterators.java:597)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterables$3.hasNext(Iterables.java:508)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.hasNext(Iterators.java:596)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.computeNext(Iterators.java:700)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.hasNext(TransformedIterator.java:43)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.computeNext(Iterators.java:700)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf(ImmutableSet.java:316)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf(ImmutableSet.java:302)
    at org.jclouds.ec2.compute.strategy.EC2ListNodesStrategy.listDetailsOnNodesMatching(EC2ListNodesStrategy.java:119)
    at org.jclouds.ec2.compute.strategy.EC2ListNodesStrategy.listNodes(EC2ListNodesStrategy.java:95)
    at org.jclouds.ec2.compute.strategy.EC2ListNodesStrategy.listNodes(EC2ListNodesStrategy.java:67)
    at org.jclouds.compute.internal.BaseComputeService.listNodes(BaseComputeService.java:339)
    at com.netflix.simianarmy.client.aws.AWSClient.getJcloudsNode(AWSClient.java:769)
    at com.netflix.simianarmy.client.aws.AWSClient.connectSsh(AWSClient.java:749)
    at com.netflix.simianarmy.chaos.ChaosInstance.connectSsh(ChaosInstance.java:123)
    at com.netflix.simianarmy.chaos.ChaosInstance.canConnectSsh(ChaosInstance.java:101)
    at com.netflix.simianarmy.chaos.ScriptChaosType.canApply(ScriptChaosType.java:61)
    at com.netflix.simianarmy.basic.chaos.BasicChaosMonkey.pickChaosType(BasicChaosMonkey.java:141)
    at com.netflix.simianarmy.basic.chaos.BasicChaosMonkey.doMonkeyBusiness(BasicChaosMonkey.java:121)
    at com.netflix.simianarmy.Monkey.run(Monkey.java:134)
    at com.netflix.simianarmy.Monkey$1.run(Monkey.java:155)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

    Caused by: org.jclouds.http.HttpResponseException: request: POST https://ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ HTTP/1.1  [Action=DescribeInstances&Signature=**** &SignatureMethod=***& SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=****&Version=2010-06-15&AWSAccessKeyId=****] failed with response: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
    at org.jclouds.aws.handlers.ParseAWSErrorFromXmlContent.handleError(ParseAWSErrorFromXmlContent.java:66)
    ... 49 more
     2015-04-01 10:52:54.497 - WARN  ScriptChaosType - [ScriptChaosType.java:62] Strategy disabled because SSH credentials failed
    2015-04-01 10:52:54.501 - WARN  BasicChaosMonkey - [BasicChaosMonkey.java:124] No chaos type was applicable to the instance: ****
```

Comment: Are you if you have set the right region in client.properties. Chaos monkey works per region only.

Comment: @shafi Thanks for replying. Yes i have tried to set  the region, but still i am getting same error. Please can you tell how to resolve this error. I am not able to proceed further

Comment: There is been not much support by community as well. Some issue with SSH class files. Its unable to ssh & push file.